# Uniform lower bound of positive-definite Hessian on unit sphere

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, convex-analysis, hessian-matrix

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}$ be twice continuously differentiable with positive-definite Hessian (denoted by $\nabla^{2}f$), i.e., for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, we have $y^{\top}\nabla^{2}f(x)y>0$. Is it possible to find some $\mu>0$ such that
\begin{equation}
   y^{\top}\nabla^{2}f(x)y\geq\mu\lVert y\rVert^{2}
\end{equation}
holds for all $x\in B_{1}(0)$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$? Here, $B_{1}(0)$ denotes the (closed) unit sphere.

Comment: Not for $n=1$ and $f(x)=e^x$.

Comment: But isn't $1/\mathrm{e}$ a uniform lower bound on $f^{\prime\prime}$ on $[-1,1]$?

Comment: I misread: $x$ is bounded.  Of course such a $\mu$ exists, by continuity of $\nabla^2f$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B_1(0)$ is compact and the minimal eigenvalue of $\nabla^2f$ depends continuously on $x$. (See [this MSE Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1010822/continuity-of-eigenvalues-and-spectral-radius-for-a-general-matrix) for details & references.) Let  $\mu$ be the minimal eigenvalue of $\nabla^2f$, attained at some $x\in B_1(0)$.  If $\mu=0$ then  $\nabla^2f(x)$ is singular, and hence fails to be positive definite. So $\mu>0$.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you use the extreme value theorem with $\mu=\min_{x\in B_{1}(0)}\lambda_{\min}(\nabla^{2}f(x))$?

Comment: And can the above statement still be proven when $B_{1}(0)$ refers to the open unit sphere? Presumably not...

Comment: Yes: extreme value theorem (in the form given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem#Generalization_to_metric_and_topological_spaces for compact spaces).  And you are right about the "presumably not": let for example  $f(x)=\tanh(x-1)$, which has an inflection point at $x=1$, where $f''$ vanishes, even though $f'''>0 $ on $(-1,1)$.

Comment: I meant, ... $f''>0$, of course.

Comment: @kimchilover, is there any such function on unit sphere instead of $\mathbb{R}^n$? Thanks.